# Request timeout on Cloud Run limits grpc stream time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stream, timeout, grpc, google-cloud-run

I am having bidirectional grpc stream on a server which is deployed on Cloud Run (Server written in Go). Time of stream is limited by Request Timeout which can not be longer than 1 hour. Grpc stream suppose to be use for long time connections. Workaround for that is to reconnect on a client side but it requires some additional implementations on a client and server side to provide continuous operations. Is there a little bit more "elegant" way to handle long time continous grpc streams via Cloud Run ?